# OpenCV - Machine learning with Image Colors

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, colors

I want to do a program in which:

Input = Image
Output = What color does it have

Im new to Machine Learning, and i want to learn. But i really don't know where to start. Can somebody give me some pointers? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try looking into [scikit-image](https://scikit-image.org) library if you're familiar with Python. You don't really need machine-learning, just a lot of processing for this.
If you're just trying to find the "majority" color in an image then my approach would be the following:

1. Get an array of all the RGB values in an image.
2. Find the most commonly occurring pixel values.
3. Lookup the pixel value from this [table](https://web.njit.edu/~kevin/rgb.txt.html)
4. Return the name of the color.

This should get you started on your image analysis journey.